# Error on building source code in VC 6

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-6

When I build my project in VC6, BSCMAKE reports the following error

```
Linking...    
Creating library ../../PB/bin/Debug/ICReplay.lib and object ../../PB/bin/Debug/ICReplay.exp        
Creating browse info file...    
BSCMAKE: error BK1505 : cannot read from file '../../PB/bin/TmpOut/ICReplay/Debug/ICReplay_PB.bsc'    
Error executing bscmake.exe.
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Have you looked at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81k63w1e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be 2 reasons as per reference from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81k63w1e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx :

> "ICReplay_PB.bsc" file will be corrupted
>
> File truncation will be happening to the compiler running out of disk space or being interrupted while creating the .sbr file

I guess this answer will help you!